# Does ImageMagick have a frame limit when creating animated gif?

Tags: png, animated-gif, imagemagick-convert

I'm trying to convert some 350 images into a single animated GIF, using ImageMagick's convert:

```
convert -delay 4 -loop 0 *.png anim.gif
```

However, for unknown reasons it creates a file with only 115 frames. I used the `verbose` option, but it only shows a jump from the 114th PNG image to the last one.

What may be going on? I'm using ImageMagick 6.9 on Debian 10.

Comment: The limit will depend upon your available RAM and/or hard disk space. You are likely running out of RAM. How large are your frames?

Comment: @fmw42 Probably not memory or disk, as I have 8 GB RAM (which jumps from 20% to 30% used when performing this task). SSD has 8.8 GB available. Each frame is a black and white line graph, 1080x1080 8-bit sRGB PNG around 40 kB (or 50 kB if converted to GIF, and 353*50 kB = negligible 18 MB).

Comment: If you are using IM 6, then each frame will be 32-bits in RAM in ImageMagick time 1080x1080 times 115 or 4bytes*1080*1080*115=536544000 bytes for the input and similarly for the output. So about 2 GB.  But you may not have enough room in your tmp directory, especially if ImageMagick has crashed and left old large files.  Check your tmp directory.

Comment: @fmw42 Similarly for the output? `identify` says the animated gif has 115 8-bit frames, and the file size is 5.5 MB. But I see, you said in RAM. Anyway, my `/` partition has 5.1 GB available. On `/tmp`, `du` says 112 (kB).